# Google Firestore data organization

Tags: database, firebase, database-design, data-modeling, google-cloud-firestore

As I can see Cloud Firestore and it's collections give us much more power to organize data. For me and many others, I think, there's a basic question.

What's the better approache to store a master detail relation?

Like this : a "CARS" collection with documents that have a "MAKE" property.

I think that I need a "CARS" collection and an independent collection for "MAKES".

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have a specific need, you might be better off just have MAKE as a field each CARS document so you can query for it.

If you want to control MAKE as an enumerated field, you can create a collection called ValidMakes that has documents with ids of all the allowed Makes. In security rules, check that there exists a document with the same id as the MAKE field's value before allowing the write.

Comment: But MAKE , must came from a list of pre defined values ( a table if I have a RDMS ) or a "collection" here (?) .A hypothetical app will have an admin level and operators at this level could fill the "MAKE" collection. Other operators will add CARS but could select only MAKEs created by admins...

Comment: Have admins create a collection called ValidMakes that has documents with ids of all the allowed Makes. In security rules, check that there exists a document with the same id as the MAKE field's value before allowing the write.

Comment: Very interesting. Until now I was thinking in rules just for access control., but they can be used for something like "referential integrity". But, in this case I can just expose to the operator ( in a SELECT ) just the contents at the MAKES collection and in this case I don't need rules...( please appologize my bad English )

Comment: Security rules in Firebase do access control **and** data validation. Also see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/secure-data#secure_writes